# Is there any other substitute of papaya paste to tenderize the mutton or beef?

Tags: substitutions, beef, tenderizing, papaya

To tenderize mutton for BBQ I use fresh papaya paste, but it is not available in some areas. Are there any alternatives to papaya paste that could be easily found?

Comment: related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/89212/chemical-meat-tenderizers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chemical meat tenderizers](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/89212/chemical-meat-tenderizers)

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, though, so I'll post an answer with a link to that question.

Answer (score 3):

Your closest substitute will be pineapple, either juice or puree, which is much more widely available worldwide than green papaya.

Papaya contains a natural tenderizer called [papain](http://www.filipinochow.com/green-papaya-meat-tenderizer/); pineapple contains a different one called [bromelain](https://www.cooksinfo.com/pineapple-juice/).  While the actions of the two fruit-based tenderizers won't be exactly the same, they will be very similar.  Plus both will impart a tropical-fruit-flavor.

Your other alternative is to find dried paypaya powder.  While still hard to find in many places, you could order it over the internet, and it would keep for a long time.   The enzyme Papain survives drying*, and thus can still be used in powder form, although you'd have to experiment with quantities.

If none of that suits, see [this answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/89212/chemical-meat-tenderizers) for other ideas.

(* there are multiple references to this but they're all spammy, so no links included)